# What's the lowest periapsis of a successful orbit around the Moon?

Tags: the-moon, history, orbital-elements, record

What's the lowest periapsis of a successful orbit around the Moon ever made by a moon-orbiting spacecraft?

Theoretically, Moon-orbiters can go as low as a foot above the surface due to the lack of an atmosphere.

Edit: I discovered my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50147/lowest-possible-lunar-orbit-and-has-any-spacecraft-achieved-it?rq=1). There, my question is answered. This question can be merged.

Comment: At some point during its landing burn, any lunar lander's periapsis briefly merges with the surface of the moon, before plunging deeper inside until reaching the center of the moon. At this point the lander has touched down.

Comment: @qqjkztd Does it complete the orbit with the close-to-surface-periapsis or perform another burn to be unable to orbit more? It's clear that I'm asking on an orbit without propulsion or change, and that during deceleration burning the periapsis would change so that it's within the Moon. First sentence asks on "ever _made_".

Comment: @Giovanni I've added a few more words to your question to make that even clearer, and a few more tags. It's an interesting question! I'm still not sure if you will include a spacecrafts last complete orbit before crashing, or if you would like ot restrict to *controlled orbits* where it was done intentionally and the spacecraft continued to maneuver.

Comment: @uhoh It may include one last orbit if the spacecraft actually went through the periapsis and flew towards apoapsis again.

Comment: The PFS-2 subsatellite deployed by Apollo 16 is the lowest manmade orbiter as per the discovered duplicate question.